# css positioning problem, cannot find difference

Tags: css

I'm looking to distinguish a difference between my [troubled page](http://www.marioplanet.com/product.asp?IDnum=1) and my  [finished page](http://www.marioplanet.com) in the icon placement in my leftcol `<div>`.  For some reason, the icons on the troubled page are all over the place.

I *have* used Firebug with FF to try and find a difference, but I cannot.

I'm sorry if it's super simple but I've been looking at this for a while now, and I can't find it.

Comment: You need to separate your code. Isolate it by categories and not keep it all on one page for other people to look over. I  want to help you but won't because to me it feels like a huge waste of time as you haven't organized you code.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you got skill to build a website?
You have no idea how to use Firebug?

```
#facebookicon, #youtubeicon {
margin-left:17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In product.css you have an entry something like this:

```
#facebookicon, #youtubeicon {
margin-left: 17px;
}
```

That seems to be the problem. (I've checked with google chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Take out lines 21 and 22 on leftCol.css. There is a `left:` value on the facebook and youtube icons that is pushing them into the main column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `padding-left` if you find any trouble when using `margin-left`.